# Undefined method `merge' for 2000..2040:Range

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have rails form with `date_select` field in rails application. by default it shows 10 years from now in drop down list, but I want to access particular year in drop down. How can I do that in rails application?

Here is what I tried and I got error:

```rb
undefined method `merge' for 2000..2040:Range
```

```rb
  <div class="field columns large-3">
    <%= form.label :planned_start_date, :class=>"required" %>
    <%= form.date_select :planned_start_date, Date.today.year-20 .. Date.today.year+20, :include_blank => true, order: [:day, :month, :year], class: 'select-date' %>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accordingly to [documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-date_select) `date_select` accepts these options:

```rb
:start_year - Set the start year for the year select. Default is Date.today.year - 5 if you are creating new record. While editing existing record, :start_year defaults to the current selected year minus 5.

:end_year - Set the end year for the year select. Default is Date.today.year + 5 if you are creating new record. While editing existing record, :end_year defaults to the current selected year plus 5.
```

So just replace your range to proper options hash as:

```rb
<%= form.date_select :planned_start_date, start_year: Date.today.year - 20, end_year: Date.today.year + 20, :include_blank => true, order: [:day, :month, :year], class: 'select-date' %>
```

And this should work